# Prolog representation of list of empty lists

Tags: list, prolog, nested-lists

Is there a way in SWI-Prolog to represent a list of empty lists?
like:

```
[[],[]],
[[],[],[]],
[[],[],[],[]]
```

I want something like this

```
[[]|[]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[],[]]`, `[[],[],[]]` and `[[],[],[],[]]` are all different things - number of elements in each list is different.

Maybe you what a predicate that will be true if the argument is a list with the length of at least 1 and those elements are empty lists:

```
lel([[]]).
lel([[] | T]) :-
    lel(T).
```

Btw, `[[]|[]]` is the same as `[[]]`.